# How to merge only specific files from a pull request?

Tags: github, merge, pull-request

Is it possible to discard a file when merging a pull-request? Also, how should I edit a file if there is no conflict and then merge the pull-request?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the PR you should have two branches let's call them master and develop.

Checkout to the develop branch in your local env.

```
git checkout develop
```

Then you can discard any file in this branch with the checkout command

```
git checkout master DISCARDED_FILE_WITH_PATH
```

This command above will grab the file from the master, so basically you discard the change.

Then commit the change

```
git commit -am 'discard the file'
```

and push back to the repo

```
git push
```

If you reload the PR, the file will missing.

Comment: This is nice, but how can I ignore some of the files which are in `develop` which I do NOT want to merge to `master` ?  I am trying to merge from `develop` to `master` only the files changed in `develop`, not the files present in `develop`but absent from `master`